# Which Column is better to be used here VARCHAR or DATETIME?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, query-performance

I have a Script that uses Date to pick the day name and number of it, Something like the following

```
2018-06-04 =becomes=> Monday(04, June)
2018-06-04 =or becomes=> Monday(04) // In no need for Month
```

So What I do is creating a Column in the table using `DATETIME` datatype, Then I set the values like this

```
000-06-04 //case1
000-00-04 //case2
```

Is that a proper way to do this, Or is it better if I use `VARCHAR(18)` datatype and write it directly like this

```
Monday(04, June) //case1
Monday(04) //case2
```

---

Using `DATETIME` requires me to use `DATE_FORMAT()` later on, And using `VARCHAR(18)` doesn't.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W(%d, %m)') FROM table //case1
SELECT date FROM table //case2
```

I'm don't care about ease of use But performance.

Comment: Do you really needs to format data in the server-side? Why not let UI layer handle it? They normaly can handle it better an if in a client-side (browser) can do it localized using the client CPU

Comment: If you're never going to modify the date again, you CAN save it as a varchar and in fact save a albeit trivial amount of time not converting it.  However, any join, or where clause you use it in will have a NON-trivial performance penalty, so I'd stick to datetime.

Comment: @jean Wouldn't that make the website pretty slow for weak and old devices? since it depends on the client device?

Comment: Unless you are rendering hundreds (maybe thousands) pages reports on the device it will smoth handle it. Also we generaly worry more about how it will show on new devices since old devices means old browsers and it's not pratical to spent too much resrouces just to keep retro compatibility to a negligible fraction of potential users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by manual `DATE` type internally represented by 3 bytes that is smallest possible for the required type of data. `TIMESTAMP` is represented internally as `BIGINT` seconds since epoch (4 bytes) but `TIMESTAMP` is always forced to be converted to/from the UTC if server's TZ is not UTC. That can cause significant overhead. `DATE` is compatible with date-related functions like `week()` or `monthname()` so it's look like the best choice.

`DATE` is far more efficient for search/sort/join/group/between than `VARCHAR(18)` so `VARCHAR()` isn't even an option.

Answer (score 3):

Any column that MySQL can treat blindly as a string (or blob) may as well be such.

Any column that MySQL needs to compare, sort, etc, should be stored in some way that is convenient for MySQL, even if it means converting while storing or fetching.  As a corollary to this, do *not* worry about the cost of `DATE_FORMAT()` and `MONTH()` when you need the display format to be anything other than `yyyy-mm-dd`.

`DATE` has 3 components, not 2:  year-month-day.  If you don't have a year, then you really don't have what MySQL thinks of as a "date".  If the user does not provide a Year, either explicitly or implicitly, then `DATE` is not practical -- there is no yearless `DATE`.  "Monday June 4" occurs in about 14 years every century.

(Not directly related.)  In almost all situations, it is not a good idea to store `DATE` and `TIME` separately.  It is easy to split a `DATETIME` into its parts; it is hard to go the other direction (eg, for a range test or `ORDER BY`).

Should you store the day of month, day of week, and month separately?  If you manipulate or test them separately, then perhaps.